# how to write code about drawable xml programmatically

Tags: android

I searched for this subject, and can't found answer enough to me. So I ask it at here.
I want to translate drawable xml code to class file code programmatically.
But I don't have any background knowledge about this.
I want to add shape that has corners, solid, stroke and so on in item.
Is there any way to study about this?

*xml code*

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorOrange"/>
            <stroke android:color="#fff" android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of drawable classes in `android.graphics` package. For your case, the one you are looking for is [ShapeDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable).

Example:

```kotlin
val shape = ShapeDrawable(RectShape()).apply {
    paint.color = 0XFFFFFFF
    paint.strokeWidth = 1f
    ....
}
```

Comment: thank you for your concern. I need to know how to add corners and solid.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape>
```

You can try it. I think it will work. I haven't run this code at all.